# Labels crosses yAxis

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

[image]

I just plotted multiple Boxplots with `ggarrange()` and labeled ("A", "B") each of them.
But why does the "B" cross the yAxis?
How can I change it?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including your code and a snippet of your data or some fake data.